# Nested ng-repeat in Angular JS table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am a newbie to Angular JS.
I have been trying iterate through a model collection and display the same in a table.

The Model looks like :

```
var myModule = angular
                .module("myModule", [])
                .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                    var countries = [
                        {
                            name: "UK",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "London"},
                                    {name: "Birmingham" },
                                    {name: "Manchestar" }
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/UK.gif"
                        },
                        {   
                            name: "USA",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "Los Angeles"},
                                    {name: "Houston"},
                                    {name: "Florida"},
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/USA.png"
                        }
                    ];
                    $scope.countries = countries;
                });
```

And I want the table structure to be

```
Country City1  City2      City3      Flag
UK      London Birmingham Manchestar .....
USA     ...... .........  .........  .....
```

But I could not do the same in the html page.

So far the code looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/MyModuleScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>City 1</th>
                    <th>City 2</th>
                    <th>City 3</th>
                    <th>Flag</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="country in countries">
                <tr ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                    <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{......}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to do to achieve the same ? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. you must put ng-repeat on td instead of row.

```js
var myModule = angular
                .module("myModule", [])
                .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.countries = [
                        {
                            name: "UK",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "London"},
                                    {name: "Birmingham" },
                                    {name: "Manchestar" }
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/UK.gif"
                        },
                        {   
                            name: "USA",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "Los Angeles"},
                                    {name: "Houston"},
                                    {name: "Florida"},
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/USA.png"
                        }
                    ];
                   
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>City 1</th>
                    <th>City 2</th>
                    <th>City 3</th>
                    <th>Flag</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="country in countries">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
                    <td  ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                        {{city.name}}
                    </td>
                  <td><img ng-src="{{country.flag}}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your prompt answer :)

Answer (score 2):

repeat a little and it works as you need it.

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="country in countries">        
                <tr >                    
                    <td >{{ country.name }}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                        {{city.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td><img ng-src="{{country.flag}}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

```js
var myModule = angular
                .module("myModule", [])
                .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                    var countries = [
                        {
                            name: "UK",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "London"},
                                    {name: "Birmingham" },
                                    {name: "Manchestar" }
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/UK.gif"
                        },
                        {   
                            name: "USA",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "Los Angeles"},
                                    {name: "Houston"},
                                    {name: "Florida"},
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/USA.png"
                        }
                    ];
                    $scope.countries = countries;
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body  ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>City 1</th>
                    <th>City 2</th>
                    <th>City 3</th>
                    <th>Flag</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="country in countries">
                
                <tr >                    
                    <td >{{ country.name }}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                        {{city.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td><img ng-src="{{country.flag}}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var myModule = angular
                .module("myModule", [])
                .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                    var countries = [
                        {
                            name: "UK",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "London"},
                                    {name: "Birmingham" },
                                    {name: "Manchestar" }
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/UK.gif"
                        },
                        {   
                            name: "USA",
                            cities: [
                                    {name: "Los Angeles"},
                                    {name: "Houston"},
                                    {name: "Florida"},
                            ],
                            flag:"/Images/USA.png"
                        }
                    ];
                    $scope.countries = countries;
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine except your HTML.

Your first `ng-repeat`  for countries should be for `<tr>`

The second one should be for `<td>`

`tbody` is not supposed to be repeated as seen by some of the answers here. As per [w3c HTML5 Specs tbody](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element) `tbody` is single element after `thead`

You are on the right track just remember that `ng-repeat` will repeat the element on which it is specified as attribute.

```
    <tbody>        
        <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">                    
            <td >{{ country.name }}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                {{city.name}}
            </td>
            <td><img ng-src="{{country.flag}}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```